# Stop extending desktop to only GPU for CUDA

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, display, cuda, gpgpu

I have a GTX570 in a win7 machine that I use for CUDA GPGPU work. I am getting some device timeouts; the solution to this is to perform computations on a second card with no displays extended to it.

Is it possible to stop extending the display to a card and in doing so circumvent the timeout restriction? (i would then remote desktop in)

Note: I have tried unplugging the monitor and disabling the card in device manager. If I disable the card in device manager I can no longer do any GPU computations.

Answer (score 1):

You can just edit your TDR settings.  We share information about that in the [ArrayFire/Jacket Documentation](http://wiki.accelereyes.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ:_Programming_and_Development#What_is_Timeout_Detection_and_Recovery_and_why_should_I_care.3F).  No need to disable your GPU in Device Manager.